# How to get a list of all displays of every view?

Tags: 7, views

I'm doing some test and I'm trying to get a list of all the displays of every view to do the test things in every display of every view, but I don't have any idea how to do it.
When using `views_get_all_views()` I only get the first display of every view, but what I want is every view and everything inside that view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find the following drush one-liner to list all the views including all display names:

```
drush eval 'foreach (views_get_all_views() as $view) { foreach ($view->display as $display => $data) { print "$view->name: $display\n"; }; }'
```

Modify the code as required.

Comment: thanks, its seems getting to what i want but... somehow it only shows me the view name, i cannot (or don't know how to) reach things like title or path

Comment: Use: `var_dump($view);`, `dsm($view);`, `dd($view);` to browse through $view object. It's quite big, so it's a bit painful. Otherwise google what you're looking for, or edit the view, export it, and check in the exported code for the appropriate object paths.

Comment: i've tried with var_dump (using simpletest, not drush, i don't know how to use drush) and i'm tring to get the path using $data->{'handler'}->{'display_options'}['path'] and i get "" i tried every way i know to get that data but i don't get it :S

Comment: Check: [How to get the path for a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884091/how-to-get-the-path-for-a-view).